# Eclipse regex search/replace not replacing after regex positive look-ahead?

Tags: regex, eclipse

After I do a positive lookahead in eclipse 3.5, I am unable to do any sort of replace! Specifically, I put in *any* text string to replace the found string, and the text string is unable to be replaced. My positive lookahead is at the end of the line so as to include the positive lookahead text in the next search.

What's up? This is also a problem in the latest Aptana Studio, which is based on eclipse.

Example:

```
-Hello!  
I'm trying to match  
some stuff  
-Hello!  
Burbpaoiwjf  
paowijefpioj  
-Hello!
```

Match pattern:

```
(?s)-Hello!(.*?)(?=-Hello!)
```

This will match, but I can't replace the matched text with anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481).

As a work-around, change your search pattern to:

```
(?s)-Hello!(.*?)-Hello!
```

And include

```
-Hello!
```

in your replace string.

Comment: ...terrible. This really sucks. I have some pretty complex matching. :(

Comment: Wow, that bug is still unresolved after more than 15 years...