# Aptana Studio 3 Find/Replace RegExp not replacing captured text

Tags: regex, aptana

Using the Aptana Studio 3 I have successfully captured lines of text using `^(.+)$` and replacing the found expressions using `<p>\1</p>`.

For example:
`This is a line of text.` yields `<p>This is a line of text.</p>`

However, when I try to replace "Note" in `Note - this is a line of text` with `<strong>Note</strong>`.

`^(.+)(?= -)` selects all of the text before the " -" (the word "Note") in the example above, but

<strong>\1</strong>
does not replace it with `<strong>Note</strong>`
After trying some online resources, I was able to get <strong>$0</strong> to work online but not in Aptana. Anyone have a solution?

By the way, "Note" is the briefest example I could provide. Many lines contain multi-word phrases before the "-".

Answer (score 2):

What's strange! Aptana seems not allow to make any replace when you use a lookahead (probably a bug), but match anyway. I have reproduced it on Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603. Notice that there's no problem with a lookbehind.

You can use that:

```
find:    ^(.+)( -)
replace: <strong>\1</strong>\2
```

[edit]

It is a know Bug: [Eclipse regex search/replace not replacing after regex positive look-ahead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312638/eclipse-regex-search-replace-not-replacing-after-regex-positive-look-ahead)

Comment: Thank you -- that worked like a charm! Now, I have to mentally adjust to incorporating the lookahead into the replacement string. I'd vote your answer up, but this is my first post and it seems I lack the track record to actually vote.